# Hibernate criteria query from a simple SQL query (with nested subquery)

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to make a query in hibernate "criteria" (not in hql) but I am not getting what to do or what to use.

```sql
select * from foo where column1 = 8 and column2 not in (
    select column2 from foo where column1 = 11 
)
```

I made it with two different queries and then use Java function to get the result, BUT I need one single criterion query for it.

Comment: Hibernate criteria is usually written in native SQL, but not in HQL. And it also contains only what goes after "WHERE".

Comment: jubinPatel, Since this seems to be what you really wanted to ask, from [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12618887/331508), you should close and delete that question as **this is a duplicate otherwise.**

Comment: thanks for suggestion,i try it but i cant do it.

Comment: Yeah, you don't have enough rep yet.  Couple things you can do: (1) Edit the question to just say that it is a duplicate, and please close it, (2) Open a question on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) asking for the question to be deleted.  Or, if you get 15 rep, you can flag the question for a moderator.

Comment: The query is not quite the same as in the previous question.  I suspect a typo here that you might want to correct.

Comment: Can you post the Java code for the involved entities (or part of it showing the relationships)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modulo knowing what your actual entity mappings are (and this is of course thoroughly untested), it's likely solved by something resembling

```
Session hibernateSession = ... (however you get it).

DetachedCriteria d = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Foo.class)
      .add(Restrictions.eq("column1", 11))
      .setProjection(Projections.property("column2"));

Criteria criteria = hibernateSession.createCriteria(Foo.class)
      .add(Restrictions.eq("column1", 8))
      .add(Subqueries.propertyNotIn("column2", d));

List<Foo> result = criteria.list();
```

This will almost certainly need adjustment, as "column1" and "column2" are sql field names, and what you need in these places are java properties.

Answer (score 0):

Create a criteria select all `Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Your.class); List list = cr.list();`
Then you can add you restriction to it, i.e. where column 1=8 etc like this:`cr.add(Restrictions.eq("YourCondition", YourCondition));`

Finally, you can provide the not in clause like this:`crit.add(Restrictions.not(Restrictions.in("YourNotInCondition", YourNotInCondition)));`

Comment: i made it like that but for 2nd condition i am not getting proper solution

Comment: Did you try nesting your restriction inside the NOT IN?

Comment: if u have any proper place where i can find it or see at least one example

Comment: I haven't tried any nesting before if I do find something, I'll let you know.